# Saving a snapshot of the state of several models literally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm fairly new to programming, and I'm developing a bookkeeping app in Rails for an analytical lab. When logging maintenance events, it would be useful to save a snapshot of certain data from associated models literally. In other words we have instruments, testing methodologies for the instruments, and maintenance events performed on the instruments, but methodologies are changeable, so it would be nice to have a static record of the state of the methodology when a maintenance is performed.

Is it good database design to simply create a separate snapshot/state model that just stores the data from the associated models literally? This makes sense to me but I'm new enough to programming to be wary of forming bad habits. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have the models `Instrument`, `Methodology` and `MaintenanceEvent`. I would simply assign to each maintenance event the methodology that has been used:

```
class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :maintenance_events
end

class MaintenanceEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instrument
  has_one :methodology
end

class Methodology < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :maintenance_event
end
```

Then you'll be able to access the methodology used during a maintenance event on a certain instrument. For example, to know what methodology has been used on a microscope during its last maintenance:

```
Instrument.find_by_name("Microscope XY").maintenance_events.last.methodology
```

Comment: I see what you mean but I think I may have misstated my question a bit. To give a bit more detail: Instruments have many methodologies, and methodologies have many analytes. Because we may refine or change the analytes listed under a methodology, our data integrity crumbles when an analyte is edited or removed from a methodology that a maintenance event references. Consequently it seems like I can either a) disallow true editing of methodologies and just save a new one on every edit or b) save associated snapshots/states of the methodology as it was during the maintenance event.

Comment: I see two possibilities here. If it is needed for some other reason you could keep track of those changes by using an `has_many :through` association that puts a middle agent in between the methodologies and the analytes and has a e.g. `valid_until` column. In this way there's no inconsistency. The other solution would be to attach both the methodology and the analyte to your maintenance events without explicitly stating that they are linked, you just save them in two columns and then retrieve them when you need it.